# What is ${@:$#} exactly?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, arguments

I tried to to run `echo ${@:$#}` and it echoes my current shell.

I found out that `echo ${#}` echoes 0.

I didn't find any resources about the results.

I am trying to understand that part so I can understand a docker script that I want to use. The script is:

```
alias enhance='function ne() { docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)/`dirname ${@:$#}`":/ne/input -it alexjc/neural-enhance ${@:1:$#-1} "input/`basename ${@:$#}`"; }; ne'
```

Comment: There is no need to encapsulate a function in an alias. It just adds an unnecessary layer.

Comment: (and as another aside, it's more portable not to use the (POSIX-noncompliant, borrowed from legacy ksh for compatibility with pre-POSIX ksh releases but not actually fully compatible with ksh's behavior) `function` keyword at all -- see both entries in the first and last tables in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete; thus, it's better just `ne() { docker run ...; }`, and that'll define a `ne` you can run as-is; no `alias`, no `function`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[In every POSIX compliant shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02),

- `$#` is the number of arguments to the function or script, the number of positional parameters.
- `$@` is the list of arguments to the function or script, the list `$1`, `$2`, etc. of positional parameters.

[In Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), [Ksh](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/ksh/ksh93.1.en.html) and [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), etc.:

- `${@:offset:n}` are the `n` arguments starting at parameter `offset`, or all arguments to the end from `offset` if `n` is missing.

Thus `${@:$#}` is the last argument given to the function at hand, whereas `${@:1:$#-1}` is the remaining arguments. The last argument could also be written `${@: -1}` (in Bash release 4.3 or later).

Comment: Note that while Bourne's `"$@"` is `"$1" "$2"...`, Korn's `"${@:offset:length}"` also includes `$0` which is not a positional parameter, but the name of the script/function (possibly sourced file). So if `$#` is 0, `${@:$#}` will be that `$0`. For the last argument, see `zsh`/`yash`'s `${@[-1]}` instead (predates the Korn syntax) or even older csh/zsh's `$argv[$#]`, or the POSIX: `eval "last=\${$#}"`