# What are some useful use-cases for eval in Shell?

Tags: shell, eval

You hear it a lot `eval is evil`, whether it's in Shell/POSIX world, or in other langs like python etc...

But I'm wondering, is it actually useless? or is it there some arcane, non-documented, interesting or just useful use-cases for it?

Would prefer if the answer is `sh`/`bash` centric, but it's fine if it's about other Shells too.

PS: I'm [well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash) [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) *why* eval is considered `evil`.

Comment: In my experience, lazy devs start concatenating strings and then call `eval` on them - I can't come up with a good reason off the top of my head why you would *want* to do this, though.

Comment: Yeah, I know; but that wouldn't be considered "useful use-cases" to me, unless it take less code to write or if it's somehow faster or have some other advantages @Panki

Comment: The often-linked-to [BashFAQ page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) (some answers to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23111/315749 point there too) includes an "Examples of good use of eval" section.

Comment: See also [What is the "eval" command in bash?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/250178)

Comment: `eval` is only  evil if not called properly, but not much more so than `sh`, `[`, `[[..]]`, `sed`, `printf`..., all those commands than can introduce ACE vulnerabilities when not used properly.

Comment: I guess that `echo "something$(somecommandoutput)" | bash` could be considered `evil` too? (since you mentioned `sh`,`sed` etc) @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Yes, any interpreter of any not-too-basic language including sh/bash/gsed/awk/perl... can interpret code  that can run arbitrary command. `eval` is just another way to invoke your shell's interpreter. It's less obvious for commands like `[`, `read` or `printf` which could be seen  as more evil for that reason.

Comment: A search here will give you some examples. For instance a [search of eval in my own posts](/search?q=user%3A22565+eval) returns 343 results ATM.

Comment: The general form of "eval is evil" is because the program running in the interpreter can invoke the interpreter; therefore the program cannot be compiled. Mechanized processing cannot determine what the code does.

Comment: I recently reasoned with my students (not demonstrated!) how you could program with a Lego EV3 robot running pybricks. You need a colour sensor, some black and white construction paper, and a non-colour background. Have a loop to check colour sensor for black or white in blocks of 8, then convert from bin to dec to ASCII and concatenate to a string. Use `00000000` to terminate input. Then `eval` the string. It takes 12 * 8 = 96 colour sensings to enter `print(':)')`. Oh, wait... you said "useful"...

Comment: Well, I'd admit the way i used the term `useful` is a bit broad *but*, in your case, it could be considered that, given this is in the context of teaching...beside that, this probably wouldn't apply here since it use Python (and this post is more or less shell-centric) @LukeSawczak I appreciate that you talked about your experience though! it is an interesting use of eval.

Answer (score 12):

I know of two ... common ... use cases for `eval`:

1. Argument processing with [`getopt`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/getopt.1.en.html#DESCRIPTION):

   > [T]his implementation can generate quoted output which must once again be interpreted by the shell (usually by using the eval command).
2. Setting up an [SSH agent](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/openssh-client/ssh-agent.1.en.html#DESCRIPTION):

   > [T]he agent prints the needed shell commands (either sh(1) or csh(1) syntax can be generated) which can be evaluated in the calling shell, eg `` eval `ssh-agent -s` `` for Bourne-type shells such as sh(1) or ksh(1) and `` eval `ssh-agent -c` `` for csh(1) and derivatives.

Both uses might have alternatives, but I wouldn't bat an eyelid on seeing either of them.

Comment: Didn't know about the first use-case, although yeah, for the second one, one could just use ``ssh-agent -s`` (using "`") instead of eval...so the second one wouldn't really be useful if it already use grave accent , thus not needing eval afaik

Comment: That depends - `eval` should still result in the output being parsed like a command line, without it you're relying on word splitting (which might be disabled, or you might have a different IFS set for whatever reason, etc.). Anyway, as I said, both might have alternatives - but they're good enough uses that the respective manpages mention them.

Comment: Didn't thought about the possibility of word splitting, guess that's useful in those cases yeah :)

Comment: Here's [the canonical `getopt` example script for bash](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash)

Comment: @NordineLotfi, `ssh-agent` prints stuff like `SSH_AGENT_PID=32442; export SSH_AGENT_PID; echo Agent pid 32442;`, and the variable assignments _don't_ work without the eval. Try e.g. `$(echo FOO=123)`. Though if it did output `export FOO=123 BAR=456`, that would work, but it couldn't then also have the shell run the `echo` (it can't print that itself, since output is caught by the command substitution). Also, without eval, it couldn't use quotes to have values with whitespace, not that it usually needs to do it.

Comment: Note that you should use `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` if IFS can be an issue. Also, I think  `getopts` exists as the eval-free alternative to `getopt`.

Comment: I see, didn't thought of that either :D @ilkkachu

Comment: Long before `ssh-agent` there was `tset`, which was used similarly with `eval`.

Comment: `getopt(1)` cannot deal with spaces in arguments and thus is obsolete since 35 years. So why do you mention examples with istric and dead software?

Answer (score 9):

To get the last argument in a POSIX shell without extensions like Bash & Co.
slicing (i.e. `${@: -1}`), one can use

```
eval "v=\${$#}"
```

`$#` is not subject to nasty tricks, since it is internal to the shell and can
only contain the number of arguments to the script/function.

<sup>I did not come up with that, it was [Stéphane Chazelas in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637828/what-is-exactly/637835#comment1195179_637835). It is also mentioned in [this answer to *why and when should eval use be avoided?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278456).</sup>

Answer (score 6):

With bash, because [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) [happens before](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)
[Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```bsh
$ char="F"
$ range=( {A.."$char"} )
$ declare -p range
declare -a range=([0]="{A..F}")
$ eval "range=( {A..$char} )"
$ declare -p range
declare -a range=([0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C" [3]="D" [4]="E" [5]="F")
```

Answer (score 6):

Some examples of my own "real-world" use-cases where I couldn't come up with better alternatives and `eval` just gets the job done neatly.

---

A "conditional-expansion" use-case. Here I want to use a redirection only if `$rmsg_pfx` has some value:

```
eval 'printf -- %s%s\\n "$rmsg_pfx" "$line" '"${rmsg_pfx:+>&2}"
```

I couldn't do it without `eval` because then the `>&2` bit would expand as an argument for `printf` instead of as its redirection.

I could instead duplicate that line to account for `$rmsg_pfx` being empty or not, but that would be.. well.. code duplication.

---

Speaking of redirections, and as an "indirection" use-case, I like relying on the `{varname}>&...` redirection syntax, which I emulate POSIXly like in below:

```bsh
# equivalent of bash/ksh `exec {rses_fd0}>&- {rses_fd1}<&-` redirection syntax
eval "exec $rses_fd0>&- $rses_fd1<&-"
```

The above is for closing fds, and likewise I'm doing an analogous indirection for emulating the opening of fds. Obviously `$rses_fd0` and `$rses_fd1` are script's internal variables, completely under its control from start to end.

---

Sometimes I had to use `eval` to simply "protect" snippets of shell code meant to target specific shells while not disrupting others.

For instance the piece of code below is from a script which is to be portable (POSIXly) while also embedding a few shell-specific optimizations:

```bsh
sochars='][ (){}:,!'"'\\"
# NOTE: wrapped in an eval to protect it from dash which croaks over the regex
eval 'o=; while [[ "$s" =~ ([^$sochars]*)([$sochars])(.*) ]]; do
    ...
done'
```

`dash` simply chokes on unknown (but direct) syntax at the lexical level, even when such syntax never gets in the actual code-path.

---

Another "protection" use-case, in a different sense. Sometimes I just can't be bothered of having to invent "unlikely" names for save&restore purposes. Such as in the case below where I just want `$r`'s value to be preserved:

```bsh
# wrapped in eval just to make sure that $r is not overwritten by (the call chain of) coolf
eval '
    coolf "$tmp" || return "$lerrno"'"
    return $r
"
```

---

I actually use often the trick above to preserve exit statuses from loop-suites while also doing cleanup operations, as in:

```bsh
    done <&3
    eval "unset ret vals; exec 3<&-; return $?"
}
```

Or in cases similar to the above, as a "deferred execution":

```bsh
    done
    # return boolean set by loop while also unsetting it
    eval "unset ok; ${ok:-false}"
}
```

Note that one implied intention of both snippets above is to not leave "artifacts" from the function execution, especially when the function is meant to be run interactively. For the latter case I could instead do:

```bsh
[ "${ok:-false}" = false ] && { unset ok; return 1; } || { unset ok; return 0; }
```

but looks quite rough to me.

---

Finally I had some occasional use-cases where I wanted/needed to amend, or extend, a function just slightly and on a call basis, perhaps for small behavioral changes or to support some hooking from the caller. Like a callback but in an "inline" fashion, which seemed much less cumbersome particularly when the hook snippet needs access to the function's own `$@` arguments. Naturally such snippets, fed thru variables to be subsequently `eval`-ed by the function, are either entirely static/handmade themselves or heavily pre-controlled/sanitized.

Comment: +1; Half of those make me wish all the shells had local variables with static scoping. The first one reminds me of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38310/conditional-pipeline BTW, I can't get Dash to error with that invalid expansion, `dash -c 'if false; then unset "${!trap_@}"; fi'` runs fine. Doesn't mean it wouldn't burn sooner with some other syntax extension.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for pointing that out. Yes, the syntax element has to be lexical or else the error is not triggered. Admittedly I've become accustomed to wrapping shell-specific syntaxes in `eval` as a safety default even when it wouldn't be required. I've reported a better example now, valid as of `dash` v0.5.11.3

Answer (score 4):

One of the real-life usages of `eval` that I have come across is used
in
[fluxbox.startfluxbox.dbus.diff.gz](http://ftp.slackware.com/pub/slackware/slackware64-current/source/xap/fluxbox/fluxbox.startfluxbox.dbus.diff.gz)
on Slackware. It looks like this:

```
# Start DBUS session bus:
if [ -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ]; then
   eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session)
fi
```

And even though this usage of `eval` hasn't been tested by millions
(Slackware is not very common) it does the job. Still, I would do my best
to avoid `eval` in my shell scripts. If I had a feeling I need it, for
example to implement arrays or perform variables indirection I'd
switch to Bash and if I still felt I need it I'd rethink the script
design or switch to a completely different language.

Comment: That looks the same as `xdotool` and `ssh-agent` above. But those backslashes have to be wrong, it would never work with them in the final script.

Comment: This is a part of the shell script inlined in another shell script. The full startfluxbox: https://pastebin.com/c8Chb7DK

Comment: yep, they're needed for the here-doc, so don't end up in the final product

Comment: @ilkkachu `xdotool` and `ssh-agent` "above" what?  Spacial directions aren't helpful here!

Comment: @TobySpeight well, the other, earlier answers anyway.

Comment: Should be `eval "$(dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session)"`. It makes no sense to invoke split+glob here.

Answer (score 3):

I've only ever used it years ago to make a [goto function](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070296/344926).

When I moved from Windows to Linux on my desktop, I had a lot of pre-existing `.BAT` and `.CMD` files to convert and I wasn't going to rewrite the logic for them, so I [found](https://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/) a way to do a `goto` in bash that works because the `goto function` runs `sed` on itself to strip out any parts of the script that shouldn’t run, and then evals it all.

*The below source is slightly modified from the original to make it more robust*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# BAT / CMD goto function
function goto
{
    label=$1
    cmd=$(sed -n "/^:[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*${label}/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | 
          grep -v ':$')
    eval "$cmd"
    exit
}

apt update

# Just for the heck of it: how to create a variable where to jump to:
start=${1:-"start"}
goto "$start"

: start
goto_msg="Starting..."
echo $goto_msg
# Just jump to the label:
goto "continue"

: skipped
goto_msg="This is skipped!"
echo "$goto_msg"

: continue
goto_msg="Ended..."
echo "$goto_msg"

# following doesn't jump to apt update whereas original does
goto update
```

and I do not feel guilty at all as Linus Torvalds famously said:

> From: Linus Torvalds
> Subject: Re: any chance of 2.6.0-test*?
> Date:  Sun, 12 Jan 2003 11:38:35 -0800 (PST)
>
> I think goto's are fine, and they are often more readable than large amounts of indentation. That's *especially* true if the code flow isn't actually naturally indented (in this case it is, so I don't think using goto is in any way *clearer* than not, but in general goto's can be quite good for readability).
>
> Of course, in stupid languages like Pascal, where labels cannot be descriptive, goto's can be bad. But that's not the fault of the goto, that's the braindamage of the language designer.

[Original source for the code](https://bobcopeland.com/blog/2012/10/goto-in-bash/)  (modified to make it less error prone)
[The source for the quote](http://koblents.com/Ches/Links/Month-Mar-2013/20-Using-Goto-in-Linux-Kernel-Code/)

*It's been **a while** since I've needed a* `goto` *though, as most of these old scripts have been revamped completely by now.*

Comment: This is quirky...I like! Always wanted to do this kind of batch <-> bash tinkering, but never did...guess i can change that now

Comment: `goto` has its uses in C code. (Some of those can be avoided by splitting code to smaller functions and using `return`. Some can't.) But you know, C is a language where `goto` actually exists in the language definition and is supported by the compiler. :) But emulating it by runtime source code tricks is... well, a bit insane...

Comment: @ilkkachu That's why I put the disclaimers at the end. I haven't used any goto in bash in the last 8 years, but if you're migrating from Window$ to Linux and you do have a lot of scripts to convert in a short time, it can be useful. In the meantime new scripts get developed in bash, so it's not an issue any more..

Comment: Why `grep -v ':$'`?

Comment: To answer my own comment after following the link in the answer: it was because an older version used "label:", which needed to be stripped out since it would attempt to execute the program `label:`, but the new version with initial `:` can be left in (since : is conveniently the null command), so the `grep` is superfluous.

Comment: @NickMatteo I haven't had a look at the code in a while.  I'll review it this week-end and update.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from what others have said, `eval` can also be used to more easily parse the output of a command, given that the command can output an `eval`able string. As an example, instead of trying to parse the output of

```bsh
xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowgeometry
```

you can pass `xdotool` the `--shell` option and just eval the output.

```bsh
eval "$( xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowgeometry --shell )"
```

In this case `xdotool` will output something similar to

```bsh
WINDOW=46137350
X=1290
Y=559
WIDTH=1258
HEIGHT=509
SCREEN=0
```

and `eval`ing this output will declare these variables in your shell.

Comment: `stty` is another command that produces shell-executable output - useful when your script needs to restore terminal state as it found it.

Comment: @TobySpeight, hmm, does it? I've only seen `stty -g` which produces a string readable by `stty` itself: `save_state=$(stty -g); ...; stty "$save_state"`

Comment: @ikkachu - you're right; I must have been mixing up with something else.  I think it was tty-related, and probably in the 1990s when I was mostly using HP-UX - possibly some `ttysize` utility to set `LINES` and `COLUMNS` within the shell.

Comment: @TobySpeight, most likely it was `resize` (shipped with `xterm`)

Answer (score 3):

One example where I have seen `eval` being used is in [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/).

There a bash function is created as a wrapper around the "real" program:

```bsh
module() { eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`; }
```

Then, when I want to load a module, say gcc/7.2.0, I type

```bsh
module load gcc/7.2.0
```

and `usr/bin/modulecmd` reads the environment and returns a new environment with extended paths:

```
CPP_INCLUDE_PATH=/nfs/modules/gcc/7.2.0/include:... ;export CPP_INCLUDE_PATH;
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/nfs/modules/gcc/7.2.0/include:... ;export C_INCLUDE_PATH;
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/nfs/modules/gcc/7.2.0/lib:... ;export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
LIBRARY_PATH=/nfs/modules/gcc/7.2.0/lib:... ;export LIBRARY_PATH;
...
```

These are then `eval`ed by the `module` function so that my environment changes.

Also [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) uses `eval` in a similar way; a program produces code for modifying the environment, and this is `eval`ed by a bash function so that the environment changes.

Comment: That `eval \`/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*\`` doesn't make any sense whatsoever. `$*` is the positional parameters joined (with variations among shells)  and subject to split+glob. The `\`...\`` (using the ancient form of cmdsubst)  is also subject to split+glob. Maybe you meant `eval "$(/usr/bin/modulecmd bash "$@")"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. The eval lines looks exactly like that. If I run `module load gcc/7.2.0` then `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash load gcc/7.2.0` will be called and its output will be `eval`ed.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. The `...` just represents that I shortened the full paths, which are of no interest for readers here.

Comment: I meant `\`...\`` is the ancient form of command substitution. `$(...)` is the modern one, but the main issue here is is that it's not quoted so subject to split+glob. Using `$*` and `$@`  unquoted also never make sense.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas. I agree that `$(...)` and `"$@"` is better, but I didn't write the code. You can find it [here](https://github.com/cea-hpc/modules/blob/master/init/bash.in#L60-L64). On the other hand, I don't think there is any command of `module` where arguments might contain spaces.

Comment: split+glob is about characters in `$IFS`, and globbing characters, not necessarily spaces (though the space character happens to be in the default value of `$IFS`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: This has been changed to `"$@"` few years ago, code that is pointed here is from the compatibility version of environment modules. ``...`` instead of `$(...)` does not change a thing in the situation it is used as far as I know. What is important to know is that the syntax used should work on any sh-shell from any Unix OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to make a command that takes shell code from the user like e.g. `watch` then `eval`ing such code seems acceptable.

Comment: `watch` (at least some implementations) concatenates its arguments with spaces and asks `sh` to interpret it. `eval` does the same but with the current shell (which may or may not understand `sh` syntax).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, that's kind of what I meant by acceptable. I know that `watch` in particular doesn't use `eval`, but it's a relatively minor technical difference if it did. If it *did* use `eval` instead of `sh -c`, we wouldn't suddenly worry about shell code injection because if that *was* a concern it would also apply to `sh -c`. Both are the same that way, so I'm treating them the same for this answer, the point of which is that shell code injection is not a concern when you're documented to take code as opposed to other data that's then not validated to not be code.

Answer (score 1):

I end up with 'eval' is a lot of my install scripts and build scripts when I'm doing checks with the file system.  This includes things like as bad umasks, mkdir doesn't conform to POSIX, or that there's some race condition.  I end up making trees and checking for these conditions as I go along.  Here's a chunk out of one of my scripts:

```
if test -n "$prefixes"; then
    # Don't fail if two instances are running concurrently.
    (umask $mkdir_umask &&
     eval "\$doit_exec \$mkdirprog $prefixes") ||
      test -d "$dstdir" || exit 1
    mkdir_used=true
 fi
```

There's likely better ways to handle this, but people who are better than I at scripts haven't scolded me for it yet.