# Passing a command with arguments and redirection to a function

Tags: bash, shell-script

In a Bash script, I pass a command with arguments. This works fine, except when the command includes a redirection. In that case, the redirection character is treated as an ordinary character.

```
$ cat foo
#!/bin/bash

f() {
  echo "command: $@"
  $@
}

f echo a-one a-two
f 'echo b-one b-two'
f 'echo c-one c-two > c.tmp'
# I don't want to do f echo d-one d-two > d.tmp because I want to redirect the
# output of the passed command, not the output of the f() function.

$ ./foo
command: echo a-one a-two
a-one a-two
command: echo b-one b-two
b-one b-two
command: echo c-one c-two > c.tmp
c-one c-two > c.tmp
```

As you see, this prints "c-one c-two > c.tmp" when I wanted to print "c-one c-two" to file c.tmp. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval "$@"` would do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

f() {
  echo "command: $@"
  eval "$@"
}
```

but in general it's very unsafe to use it even though you'll see it
[here and
there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640711/what-are-some-useful-use-cases-for-eval-in-shell).

Answer (score 2):

```
f() {
  echo "command: $@"
  $@
}
```

In general, you [should use `"$@"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and/94200#94200), here, too, for the [usual](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) [reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

But you're right, running a command like that doesn't process shell operators, be it redirections or stuff like `&&`. You could change the function to `eval` the command it gets, which would process redirections, but also everything else.

In particular, passing arbitrary filenames would become difficult again. E.g. this would end up running `ls` on the two files `foo` and `bar`:

```
run_with_eval() {
    eval "$@"
}
file='foo bar'
run_with_eval ls -l "$file"
```

You'd have to [arrange for the filename to be passed quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379181/170373) for the shell, which is somewhat awkward and error-prone.

But if you *only* want redirection, and even better, only output redirection with `>`, you could have the function handle it manually:

```
#!/bin/bash
run_with_redir() {
    local redir=
    if [[ $1 = '>' ]]; then
        redir=$2
        shift 2
    fi
    ## whatever else you do
    if [[ $redir ]]; then
        "$@" > "$redir"
    else
        "$@"
    fi
}

run_with_redir echo "normal command, no redirection"
run_with_redir ">" output.txt echo "this gets redirected to output.txt"
```

That is, invoking the function with `>` and a filename as the first two arguments runs the rest as a command with the output redirected. Without the `>`, it runs the command normally. Note that the `">"` must be quoted when calling the function, otherwise we'd again get the output of the whole function redirected. Expanding that to support e.g. `>>` should be straightforward, even if repetitive.

That should also work in the trickier cases:

```
run_with_redir ">" "output file with space.txt" ls -l "other file with space"
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to not use eval but it's very unsafe too.

```
#!/bin/bash

f() {
  echo "command: $@"
  bash -c "$@"
}

f echo a-one a-two
f 'echo b-one b-two'
f 'echo c-one c-two > c.tmp'
```

Comment: Using `eval` and running another full shell aren't that different. In both cases there's a full round of shell expansions etc. done. Of course, an `eval` happens in the same shell environment, while starting another shell starts another environment. But all the quoting complications and issues with files called `$(reboot)` are there. Also, here, you probably should use `bash -c "$*"` because `-c` only takes one argument. Note e.g. how the `f echo a-one a-two` only prints an empty line with function here.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, you are right. I don't look for all cases. Only want to tell the OP that's there is another way.